# React - how rendering component works

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm a bit confused about how react component works. let say i have 3 component class A, B and C. A contain B and C, and i want to render A in my HTML page

```
class A extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <B />
      <C />
    );
  }
}
```

If i change the state inside component C, do component B get re-rendered too or only component C get re-rendered? thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

More than whether C updates or B updates, I think this is a question on how Reconciliation algorithm works. 
When you perform a state update React compares this to the copy in Virtual DOM and finds out the easiest way to make the change.

As you can see, when you perform an update on B, only B updates. 
[image: This is what happens when you update B]

C, only C updates.
[image: This is what happens when you update C]

But when you perform an update on A (which is called App) A, B and C update.
[image: This is what happens when you update A]

Here is the codebase I used to perform Profiling https://codesandbox.io/s/8n9rx1py5j

You can learn how to perform Profiling in Chrome from [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#profiling-components-with-the-chrome-performance-tab)

Answer (score 0):

Only Component C and only if the state you change effects the output of your render function.

Comment: If C is a functional component or simple Component without `shouldComponentUpdate` function, C will be re-rendered if its state changes. However, there will be no DOM operations if the rendered output is the same as before changing the state.

Answer (score 0):

How better to understand what happens than with a sandbox? I've set up a sandbox to help with the same - https://codesandbox.io/s/388wxk9321

> Open up the console and click on the buttons to increment counters in `ModuleB` & `ModuleC` and then reset the state from `ModuleA`

#### For the lazy

[image]